# Event.scale is undefined on gestureend

Tags: javascript, jquery, scale, jquery-events, pinch

I'm trying to bind the "gestureend" event to my page and then output the value of event.scale to the console. The problem is that when the event is fired, the event.scale is undefined. Can someone tell me why?

```
$(document).bind('gestureend', function(event)
{
  console.log("Pinch Scale: "+event.scale);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JQuery event you require to use 
`event.originalEvent.scale`
instead of `event.scale`.